# Picturebox change if button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Hi good day guys i would just like to ask if how can I change a picture in a `PictureBox` if I clicked a button to be specific i have one picture box and one button which is `Button1` and I want to change the picture everytime I click the `Button1`. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button1_click event, you could add the following

```
PictureBox1.Image= Image.FromFile("c:\folder\file.gif")
```

Replace the path with the image you need.

EDIT

To change it everytime, you need to create a global variable 'counter'.
Add to that value everytime you click.

Also, create an array of pictures.

So everytime you click, you select the string in the array with the index of counter and you set that as the image in the code presented above.

```
Dim array() As String = {"c:\folder\file1.gif", "c:\folder\file2.gif", "c:\folder\file3.gif"}

PictureBox1.Image= Image.FromFile(array(counter))
```

Comment: That will only change the image the first time 'Button1' is clicked.

Comment: Now you will need to write every path one by one. Tremendous effort

Comment: One way or another, you have to specify the paths. Being in a file, table or in-code.
The other way is to make it dynamic, based on the previous image. But the question comes from someone that is new into programming

Comment: devcon 2 I would like to thank you from the bottom of my heart :) Both of your answers are functioning i tried it but yours is the one who is more applicable to a newbie like me....thanks again to you and to sir equisde

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `List` of `Image` contained into `Somefilepath`

```
Dim images As New List(Of Image)()
images.add(Image.FromFile(Somefilepath))
Dim imageindex as Integer 

imageIndex = 0
```

Now in a separate function you can change your pictures every time the `Button1` is clicked

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    PictureBox1.Image = images(imageIndex)
    imageIndex = imageIndex + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sir can you please elaborate the process? I am just new in programming :( Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `images` is a List of Images contained on Somefilepath. You can replace `Somefilepath` with the path of the folder which contains the images you want to show.  `imageIndex` is a index that starts with 0 and go increasing itself every time you click on the button, so when you click the button the image is changed and the index will be placed in the next image to show